# How to add a modifier to any specific buttons inside a ForEach loop for an array of buttons in SwiftUI?

Tags: animation, button, foreach, swiftui, modifier

**How can I add modifiers according to my needs to individual buttons?**

I have a `ForEach` loop running in a range of `0..<5` & I need to add an animation of `.rotation3DEffect` in clicked button and another `.opacity` on remaining un-clicked buttons, according to their state.

> *Note: I can watch for any state value inside buttons action, and then change it to have the animation, but since the modifier is applied on
> the `Button` itself inside the `ForEach` loop, I am having the animation
> applied to every buttons inside the foreach.*

```
@State private var rotationDegree = 0.0
@State private var selectedNum = 0
@State private var correctAnswer = 0 // comes from saved data

var body: some View {
    
    ForEach(0..<5) { num in // image as a button, loops through their prefix name
        
        Button {
            selectedNum = (num == correctAnswer) ? num : 0
            withAnimation {
                // once clicked, will animate all 5 buttons, need only this clicked button to animate.
                if (num == correctAnswer) {
                    rotationDegree += 360
                }
            }
            
        } label: {
            
            Image("imageName\(num)")
            
        }
        .rotation3DEffect((.degrees((selectedNum == correctAnswer) ? rotationDegree : 0.0)), axis: (x: 0, y: (selectedNum == correctAnswer) ? 1 : 0, z: 0)) // animation I want to add to a specific button
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - Popover in ForEach Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70113933/swiftui-popover-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: No, I shall add a code sample

Comment: It is the same answer everything inside the ForEach needs to go into a view of its own so each loop gets their own State. In your case num will be a parameter

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an answer, I din't get when u said; ..to go into a view of its own..

Comment: You are looking at the problem the wrong way. You aren't sharing the `Button` you are sharing the `@State` with 5 `Button`s so you need 5 `@State` to control them individually. Create a SwiftUI `View` that has in its `body` all the code in the`content` of the `ForEach`, it will also have the `@State` to control the animation, and a parameter for `num`.

Comment: I still didn't get you; I should have 5@State properties defined for each buttons and check those state properties to define my modifier??

Comment: Yes, 5 `@State` because you have 5 `Button`. But they are created programmatically in a `View` for each iteration of the `ForEach` loop. See the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnimatedListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<5) { num in
                //The content of the ForEach goes into its own View
                AnimatedButtonView(num: num)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct AnimatedButtonView: View {
    //This creates an @State for each element of the ForEach
    @State private var rotationDegree = 0.0
    //Pass the loops data as a parameter
    let num: Int
    var body: some View {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    rotationDegree += 360
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                Text(num.description)
            }
            .rotation3DEffect((.degrees(rotationDegree)), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
    }
}
struct AnimatedListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnimatedListView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your view.

```
@State var selectedNum: Int = 0
```

Then change your button to look something like this.

```
Button {
  selectedNum = num

  withAnimation {
    rotationDegree += 360
  }
} label: {
        Image("imageName\(num)")
    }
    // Check if the selected button is equal to the num
    .rotation3DEffect((.degrees(selectedNum == num ? rotationDegree : 0.0)), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
```

Not sure how the rotation3DEffect works. But here is another example

```
.background(selectedNum == num ? .red : .blue)
```

Comment: I've actually tried setting the rotationdegree to 360 degree only after button's action, but that works only when that action isn't called. Once Button's action triggers, value changes and applies to whole foreach loop, since the modifier is set inside the loop.

Comment: I've updated question's code according to your answer.

Comment: @Aashish you don't want to use a bool for a tracker once any button is click it will toggle it and run the animation. I updated the answer and it is working for me. I just didn't know how the rotation3DEffect work.

Comment: Yeah, even boolean value worked for background modifier, but not for the .rotaion3DEffect Using nil coalescing doesn't have any effect on the behaviour. But, as the accepted answer we needed to add a modifier to the view itself, and then embed them to the ForEach loop.  && thankyou so much for your effort as well.