# Al TextFields in Foreach type simultaneously in SwiftUI

Tags: foreach, swiftui, textfield

from last post I decided on creating a table as following. However, when I type inside one textfield, all other textfields in the same ForEach pass through the same input. Is there something I can do, so each textfield will have its own entity?

Additionally, is this still a good solution, for when I have a few of these inside *1* view? And is this too much in terms of too many Spacers and VStacks?

How can I track all of these inputs from the textfields individually to store in coreData?

Thanks, I appreciate any type of advice.
Kind Regards

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {

@State var B: String = ""
@State var C: String = ""


var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22)
            .fill(Color(.systemGray5))
            .frame(width: 400, height: 130, alignment: .center)
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            HStack {
                Text("A")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
Spacer()
                    ForEach(1..<6) { i in
                       Text("\(i)")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("B")
                    Spacer()
                    ForEach(1..<6) { i in
                        TextField("", text: $B)
                            .background(
                                VStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Color
                                        .primary
                                        .frame(height: 1)
                                }
                            )
                            .frame(width: 50, alignment: .trailing)

                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("C")
                Spacer()
                ForEach(1..<6) { i in
                    TextField("", text: $C)
                        .background(
                            VStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Color
                                    .primary
                                    .frame(height: 1)
                            }
                        )
                        .frame(width: 50, alignment: .trailing)

                }
            }
            
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a modifier to any specific buttons inside a ForEach loop for an array of buttons in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139071/how-to-add-a-modifier-to-any-specific-buttons-inside-a-foreach-loop-for-an-array)

Comment: Thanks very much, yes it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same variables for your `TextFields` within each `ForEach`. You need to use an array of something, and key your `ForEach` to the array. Here is a simplified version of your code. Notice how "B" duplicates your typing in each `TextField` where as "C" doesn't? The difference is that each `TextField` in "C" is accessing its own storage.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {

    @State var B: String = ""
    @State var C: [DemoText] = [DemoText(value: ""), DemoText(value: "")]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            HStack {
                Text("B")
                Spacer()
                ForEach(0..<2) { _ in
                    TextField("", text: $B)
                        .background(Color.gray)
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Text("C")
                Spacer()
                ForEach($C) { $element in
                    TextField("", text: $element.value)
                        .background(Color.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DemoText: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var value: String
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But compared to lorem ipsum's solution, which is most efficient. For now, both work great. But when the app will be used at its intended scale, what will be most efficient?