# SwiftUI: @State variable in a foreach loop

Tags: swiftui

I'm having an issue with swiftUI. I have this button:

```
                        Button {
                            isLiked.toggle()
                            print("Like Button")
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart" : "heart.fill")
                                .font(.system(size:25))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
```

I'm trying to make it so the image is changed from "heart" to "heart.fill" when pressed. This would work fine if I defined `isLiked` as an `@State` variable, however I am using multiple instances of this button in a foreach loop. How can I define a variable that can change the image if I don't know how many items I'll have?

Comment: Separate the code you showed into its own view, with its own state variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139071/how-to-add-a-modifier-to-any-specific-buttons-inside-a-foreach-loop-for-an-array/70148582#70148582