# How to make an individual selection on a ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, swiftui

I'm trying to add a checkmark to every food picture the user selects, but it gets selected on every option instead of just one.

I understand it's the `ForEach` that may be causing this. But I can't think of a way to fix this.

[The problem on the Simulator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os1Oz.png)

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                
                ForEach(comidas) { comida in
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        
                        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Image(uiImage: comida.foodImage)
                                .resizable()
                                .blur(radius: 2)
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        isChecked.toggle()
                                    }
                                }
                            
                            Text(comida.name)
                                .font(.title2)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .opacity(isChecked ? 1 : 0 )
                                .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5))
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 3)
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
//"comidas" is food in Spanish

struct Comidas: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    
    let name: String
    let foodImage: UIImage
}

let comidas = [
    Comidas(id: 0, name: "Asado", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "asado")),
    Comidas(id: 1, name: "Pizzas", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "pizzas")),
    Comidas(id: 2, name: "Milanesas", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "milanesas")),
    Comidas(id: 3, name: "Empanadas", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "empanadas")),
    Comidas(id: 4, name: "Pastas", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "pasta")),
    Comidas(id: 5, name: "Sushi", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "sushi")),
    Comidas(id: 6, name: "Facturas", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "facturas")),
    Comidas(id: 7, name: "Café", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "cafe")),
    Comidas(id: 8, name: "Helados", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "helados"))
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139071/how-to-add-a-modifier-to-any-specific-buttons-inside-a-foreach-loop-for-an-array/70148582#70148582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a reference of the selected comidas and use that to determine a comida's checked status. I prefer using a `Set` in this instance because it automatically handles duplicates and simplifies adding/removing an item.

First thing is to add `Hashable` conformance to `Comida` so that we can do `Set` operations with it. All the properties inside the `Comida` struct already conform to `Hashable` so declaring `Hashable` conformance is all you need.

```
//note that comida should be singular since it represents a single item
struct Comida: Identifiable, Hashable {
```

In your view, add a `@State` variable to track the user-selected `Comida`s

```
@State var comidasEligidas: Set<Comida> = []
```

In your tap gesture on the comida `Image`, add or remove the comida from the `comidasEligidas` `Set`

```
.onTapGesture {
    if comidasEligidas.contains(comida) {
        comidasEligidas.remove(comida)
    } else {
        comidasEligidas.insert(comida)
    }
}
```

Toggle the opacity of the check mark depending on whether the `Comida` is present in the set, and indicate that the value for which to observe animation is the `eligidasComidas` `Set`. Also, I recommend disallowing `hitTesting` on the check mark so that it doesn't swallow any touches.

```
.opacity(comidasEligidas.contains(comida) ? 1 : 0 )
.animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5), value: comidasEligidas)
.allowsHitTesting(false)
```

Here is the full code snippet:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    struct Comida: Identifiable, Hashable {
        var id: Int
        let name: String
        let foodImage: UIImage
    }

    let comidas = [
        Comida(id: 0, name: "Asado", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "asado")),
        Comida(id: 1, name: "Pizzas", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "pizzas")),
        Comida(id: 2, name: "Milanesas", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "milanesas")),
        Comida(id: 3, name: "Empanadas", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "empanadas")),
        Comida(id: 4, name: "Pastas", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "pasta")),
        Comida(id: 5, name: "Sushi", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "sushi")),
        Comida(id: 6, name: "Facturas", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "facturas")),
        Comida(id: 7, name: "Café", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "cafe")),
        Comida(id: 8, name: "Helados", foodImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "helados"))
    ]

    @State var comidasEligidas: Set<Comida> = []

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            
                ForEach(comidas) { comida in
                
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    
                        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Image(uiImage: comida.foodImage)
                                .resizable()
                                .blur(radius: 2)
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    if comidasEligidas.contains(comida) {
                                        comidasEligidas.remove(comida)
                                    } else {
                                         comidasEligidas.insert(comida)
                                    }
                                }
                        
                            Text(comida.name)
                                .font(.title2)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .opacity(comidasEligidas.contains(comida) ? 1 : 0 )
                                .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5), value: comidasEligidas)
                                .allowsHitTesting(false)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 3)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it! I really need to look at the documentation, thank you so much, appreciate it.