# SwiftUI : How I can use confirmationDialog for each row of a list?

Tags: list, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct MemoListView: View {
    
    let folder : FolderModel
    @State private var showActionSheet : Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var vm : FolderListViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if folder.memo.count == 0 {
                NoMemoView()
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(folder.memo) { memo in
                        MemoRowView(memo: memo, folder: self.folder)
                            .onLongPressGesture {
                                self.showActionSheet.toggle()
                            }
                            .confirmationDialog(Text("Option"), isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
                                Button(role : .destructive, action: {
                                    vm.deleteMemo(folder: folder, memo: memo)
                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Delete")
                                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                                })
                            }
                    }
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Memos in '\(folder.folderName)'")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                HStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: {
                        NewMemoView(folder: self.folder)
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    })
                    NavigationLink(destination: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi!
Please check my code above.
I want to apply actionSheet(confirmationDialog) to each of row in list but I think the list can't recognize which row is selected.

If I tried to delete row3, it just delete only row1

I don't know how I can handle this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a modifier to any specific buttons inside a ForEach loop for an array of buttons in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139071/how-to-add-a-modifier-to-any-specific-buttons-inside-a-foreach-loop-for-an-array)

Comment: Save the memo id in a state var before toggling show action sheet. So you can use this index as entry point in confirmation dialog which should be global to List.

Comment: Use variant with data presenting, `presenting: memo` in your case, to make content dependent on a row data. (This is the iOS15+ replacement for `actionSheet(item:`)

Comment: @Asperi , the presenting argument seems to be only available for .sheet. Did I missed something in the doc ?

Comment: Put the confirmation in the `RowView`

Answer (score 2):

As per your comments to the original post, `.confirmationDialog` only has an `isPresented` binding available, rather than an object-based one as with `sheet`, `fullScreenCover`, etc.

One workaround I've used quite successfully is to move the confirmationDialog, and the boolean state flag that drives it, into a child view. This could be `MemoRowView` itself, or you could keep that view as the presentation component only and wrap it in an interactive view that called `MemoRowView` and added the interactive elements, e.g.

```swift
// MemoListView
List {
  ForEach(folder.memo) { memo in
    MemoListItem(memo: memo, folder: self.folder)
  }
.listStyle(.plain)
```

This does mean injecting quite a lot of domain knowledge into the list item, so it'd need its own @EnvironmentObject reference, etc., but that could be lived with.

Alternatively, you could keep the code that deletes the object in the parent view, and just keep the confirmation in the child view:

```swift
struct MemoListItem: View {
  var memo: MemoModel
  var folder: FolderModel
  var onDelete: () -> Void

  @State private var showDeleteConfirmation: Bool = false

  init(memo: MemoModel, folder: FolderModel, onDelete: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.memo = memo
    self.folder = folder
    self.onDelete = onDelete
  }

  var body: some View {
    // rest of row setup omitted for brevity
    .confirmationDialog(Text("Option"), isPresented: $showDeleteConfirmation) {
      Button("Delete", role: .destructive, action: onDelete)
    }
  }
}

// MemoListView
List {
  ForEach(folder.memo) { memo in
    MemoListItem(memo: memo, folder: self.folder, onDelete: {
      vm.deleteMemo(folder: folder, memo: memo)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! thank you for your solution, but when I aligned my with memoListItem, my list view(main) is locked I mean It 's not working, can't tap can't scroll as well.

Comment: Moving the `@State` var from the parent view to the child view solves it for me. The confirmationDialog popover arrow is pointed to the correct item in the list . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An explanation of what I wrote in my comment :

```
struct MemoListView: View {   
    @EnvironmentObject var vm : FolderListViewModel
    // Updated folder so as it seems it is extracted from your 
    // view model
    var folder : FolderModel {
        vm.folder
    }
    @State private var showActionSheet : Bool = false
    // This is the way to know which memo to delete
    @State var memoToDelete: Memo?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if folder.memo.count == 0 {
                NoMemoView()
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(folder.memo) { memo in
                        MemoRowView(memo: memo, folder: self.folder)
                            .onLongPressGesture {
                                // Save the memo on the current row
                                memoToDelete = memo
                                self.showActionSheet.toggle()
                            }
                            .confirmationDialog(Text("Option"), isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
                                Button(role : .destructive, action: {
                                    // Delete the saved memo
                                    if let memo = memoToDelete {
                                        vm.deleteMemo(folder: folder, memo: memo)
                                    }
                                }, label: {
                                    // Here to show the memo id before delete
                                    if let memo = memoToDelete {
                                        Text("Delete \(memo.id)")
                                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                    }
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Memos in '\(folder.folderName)'")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                HStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: {
                        NewMemoView(folder: self.folder)
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    })
                    NavigationLink(destination: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note : I changed from the comment and kept the dialog on each row.
It is not the best way to do it.

Comment: List would open confirmation dialogs `folder.memo.count` times because they all share the same `@State` look at the answer I linked in the comments. Always test your code, this is the root of the OPs issue. Scott's answer addresses this issue too.

Comment: @loremipsum : as I wrote it is not best solution. Even if the dialog is opened multiple time (what I did not see when testing it) the upper one will close the other on dismiss also.