# Creating local variables and binding them to Textfield text

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a dynamic form, where the user can add rows of textfields as needed. I need to create and bind local variables to each of the fields in each new row. However, when I tried to use local variables with @State, the values wouldn't change and I got the warning "Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update".

```
ForEach(0..<numExercises, id: \.self) { idx in
                        // TODO: figure out a way such that we can bind local variables to the text fields
                        @State var exercise : String = ""
                        @State var sets : Int = 0
                        @State var reps : Int = 0
                        @State var weight : Double = 0.0
                        HStack(){TextField("Name", text: $exercise)
                            TextField("Sets", value: $sets, format: .number).padding()
                            TextField("Reps", value: $reps, format: .number).padding()
                            TextField("Weight", value: $weight, format : .number).padding()
                        }
                        }
```

I tried to change the @State to @Published but just got a different error. Also, I am not familiar with Swift as this is my first app, so I am not sure how to approach this. I need to make an object from data collected from each row, so that's why I need to use local variables.

Comment: Probably good to check out some SwiftUI tutorials, as there are a few things that are going to cause issues. First, `@State` should be declared at the top of your `View` struct, not inside the `body`. Second, you generally shouldn't be using indices in a `ForEach`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a modifier to any specific buttons inside a ForEach loop for an array of buttons in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139071/how-to-add-a-modifier-to-any-specific-buttons-inside-a-foreach-loop-for-an-array)

Comment: if you google "swiftui tutorial foreach" you get a lot of great results, for example: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach or https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-foreach/ - both solve problems similar to yours.

Comment: The ```@State``` and ```@Published``` wrappers use a special "magic" that only really works for properties of a ```View``` struct. In addition to that, SwiftUI ```ForEach``` is not really a for-each loop, although it looks deceptively similar. For instance, using an index as an ```id``` in ```ForEach``` is likely to lead to some unexpected results when underlying data changes. So, as recommended above, reading tutorials might be a good idea.

Comment: However, while a "correct" answer would require knowledge of the design of your data structure, I have a quick suggestion: separate contents of the ```ForEach``` block to a different ```View``` and declare ```@State``` variables as properties of that ```View```. Let me know if you need example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic forms as you mentioned in question in SwiftUI with ease. You just have to create a model class of your data and make it to Binding.

Here is my solution to your question.

Excercise.swift

```
struct Excercise {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var sets: Int = 0
    var reps: Int = 0
    var weight: Double = 0.0

    static var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        return formatter
    }()

    static var weightFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter
    }()
}
extension Excercise: Identifiable { }
```

AddExcercise.swift

```
struct AddExcerciseView: View {
    @State private var excercises = [Excercise]()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach($excercises) { excercise in
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Name", text: excercise.name)
                        HStack {
                            TextField("Sets", value: excercise.sets, formatter: Excercise.numberFormatter)
                                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                            TextField("Reps", value: excercise.reps, formatter: Excercise.numberFormatter)
                                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                            TextField("Weight", value: excercise.weight, formatter: Excercise.weightFormatter)
                                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } header: {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        excercises.append(.init(name: ""))
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddExcerciseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddExcerciseView()
    }
}
```